# CollapsiblePanelExtender doesn't open up all the way on initial page load

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit, collapsiblepanelextender

I'm using CollapsiblePanelExtender from AjaxControlToolkit, it works fine when i click on it, but it won't expand all the way on the initial page load (expands about 90%).

I have to collapse it and expand it back manually for it to open up all the way.

I don't have the ExpandedSize property set, because the panel content is dynamic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use any css reset technique ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this issue?

Comment: @mphair: no, I ended up not using the AjaxControlToolkit. This might have been fixed in recent AjaxControlToolkit's releases.

Answer (score 9):

Use the following style on the target of the extender:

```
.collapsiblePanelContainer {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The CollapsiblePanelExtender will take care of the rest of the work.

This tip is mentioned by Joe Stagner in the [CollapsiblePanelExtender video](http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax-videos/video-89.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If the data in the collapsible panels is fixed and there is no need to call a page postback, set the "SuppressPostBack" property of the CollapsiblePanelExtender to true.  This will allow the expand action to complete more quickly and smoothly.  You won't notice a delay.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the value of "min-height" in the style of the actual panel. Otherwise you can programmatically set the height or the ExpandSize in the PreRender event

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    // Set the size here
    myCollapsiblePanelExtender.ExpandedSize = sizeValue;
}
```

Comment: the size of the panel varies based on its contents